# Detecting Last Visited Storyboard

Tags: ios7, nsstring, uistoryboard

I have this piece of code below which basically opens up the last Class saved. In my instance this class is within a story board and it is transitioning to black when I tell it to recall the class it. What I want to know is how do I detect the ID of the storyboard, save it, and then open it up from an IBAction from any Storyboard in the one storyboard doc. Thanks :)

Save Code:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:NSStringFromClass([self class]) forKey:@"currentViewController"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Return Code:

```
NSString *savedClassName = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"currentViewController"];
Class cls = NSClassFromString(savedClassName);
UIViewController *screen = (UIViewController *)[cls new];
screen.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentViewController:screen animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Please elaborate what does later means here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just putting this into my Return IBAction, SO SIMPLE!!

```
[[self presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

There could be 2 issues here.

1. Your class of view controller is getting initialized but its view is not getting load from story board properly.
2. you have not provided storyboard ID to your view controller in xib file.

After confirming that both points are done you can do something like this:

```
UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"UIViewController"];
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```